# sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/!d;q' bak.sql; how does this command work?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, sed

The content of bak.sql is:

```
 1  -- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
 2  --
 3  -- Host: localhost    Database: suck_db
 4  -- ------------------------------------------------------
 5  -- Server version   5.5.60-MariaDB
 6  
 7  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 8  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 9  /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
10  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
11  /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
12  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
13  /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
14  /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
15  /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
16  /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
17  
18  --
19  -- Current Database: `suck_db`
20  --
21  
22  CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `suck_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
23  
24  USE `suck_db`;
25  
26  --
27  -- Table structure for table `suck_t`
28  --
29  
30  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `suck_t`;
31  /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
32  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
33  CREATE TABLE `suck_t` (
34    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
35    `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
36    `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
37    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
38  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
39  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
40  
41  --
42  -- Dumping data for table `suck_t`
43  --
44  
45  LOCK TABLES `suck_t` WRITE;
46  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` DISABLE KEYS */;
47  INSERT INTO `suck_t` VALUES (1,'tom1',11),(2,'tom2',11),(3,'tom3',11),(4,'tom4',11),(5,'tom5',11),(6,'tom5',11),(7,'tom5',11),(8,'tom5',11),(9,'tom5',11),(10,'tom5',11),(11,'tom5',11),(12,'tom5',11),(13,'tom5',11),(14,'tom5',11),(15,'tom5',11),(16,'tom5',11),(17,'tom5',11),(18,'tom5',11),(19,'tom5',11),(20,'tom5',11),(21,'tom5',11),(22,'tom5',11),(23,'tom5',11),(24,'tom5',11),(25,'tom5',11),(26,'tom5',11),(27,'tom5',11);
48  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` ENABLE KEYS */;
49  UNLOCK TABLES;
50  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
51  
52  /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
53  /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
54  /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
55  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
56  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
57  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
58  /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
59  
60  -- Dump completed on 2018-12-12  1:02:27
```

When I run

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/!d;q' bak.sql
```

the output is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `suck_t`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `suck_t` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

The purpose of this command is to extract the create tables sectors from the `bak.sql` file.

I'm really confused, how does it work?

And `{H;$!d;}`, why should there be braces? What's the difference between braces and without braces?

My understanding is, 
After '/./{H;$!d;}' is executed, the pattern space includes 10 empty lines and the last line, the hold space includes all the non-empty lines. 
i.e.

the pattern space is:

```
 1  
 2  
 3  
 4  
 5  
 6  
 7  
 8  
 9  
10  
11  -- Dump completed on 2018-12-12  1:02:27
```

the hold space is:

```
 1  -- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
 2  --
 3  -- Host: localhost    Database: suck_db
 4  -- ------------------------------------------------------
 5  -- Server version   5.5.60-MariaDB
 6  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 7  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 8  /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 9  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
10  /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
11  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
12  /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
13  /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
14  /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
15  /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
16  --
17  -- Current Database: `suck_db`
18  --
19  CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `suck_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
20  USE `suck_db`;
21  --
22  -- Table structure for table `suck_t`
23  --
24  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `suck_t`;
25  /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
26  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
27  CREATE TABLE `suck_t` (
28    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
29    `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
30    `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
31    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
32  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
33  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
34  --
35  -- Dumping data for table `suck_t`
36  --
37  LOCK TABLES `suck_t` WRITE;
38  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` DISABLE KEYS */;
39  INSERT INTO `suck_t` VALUES (1,'tom1',11),(2,'tom2',11),(3,'tom3',11),(4,'tom4',11),(5,'tom5',11),(6,'tom5',11),(7,'tom5',11),(8,'tom5',11),(9,'tom5',11),(10,'tom5',11),(11,'tom5',11),(12,'tom5',11),(13,'tom5',11),(14,'tom5',11),(15,'tom5',11),(16,'tom5',11),(17,'tom5',11),(18,'tom5',11),(19,'tom5',11),(20,'tom5',11),(21,'tom5',11),(22,'tom5',11),(23,'tom5',11),(24,'tom5',11),(25,'tom5',11),(26,'tom5',11),(27,'tom5',11);
40  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` ENABLE KEYS */;
41  UNLOCK TABLES;
42  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
43  /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
44  /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
45  /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
46  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
47  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
48  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
49  /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
50  -- Dump completed on 2018-12-12  1:02:27
```

After 'x' is executed, hold space and pattern space is switched, so the pattern space includes all the non-empty lines and the hold space includes a bunch of empty lines and the last line.

the pattern space is:

```
 1  -- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
 2  --
 3  -- Host: localhost    Database: suck_db
 4  -- ------------------------------------------------------
 5  -- Server version   5.5.60-MariaDB
 6  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 7  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 8  /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 9  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
10  /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
11  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
12  /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
13  /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
14  /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
15  /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
16  --
17  -- Current Database: `suck_db`
18  --
19  CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `suck_db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
20  USE `suck_db`;
21  --
22  -- Table structure for table `suck_t`
23  --
24  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `suck_t`;
25  /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
26  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
27  CREATE TABLE `suck_t` (
28    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
29    `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
30    `age` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
31    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
32  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
33  /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
34  --
35  -- Dumping data for table `suck_t`
36  --
37  LOCK TABLES `suck_t` WRITE;
38  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` DISABLE KEYS */;
39  INSERT INTO `suck_t` VALUES (1,'tom1',11),(2,'tom2',11),(3,'tom3',11),(4,'tom4',11),(5,'tom5',11),(6,'tom5',11),(7,'tom5',11),(8,'tom5',11),(9,'tom5',11),(10,'tom5',11),(11,'tom5',11),(12,'tom5',11),(13,'tom5',11),(14,'tom5',11),(15,'tom5',11),(16,'tom5',11),(17,'tom5',11),(18,'tom5',11),(19,'tom5',11),(20,'tom5',11),(21,'tom5',11),(22,'tom5',11),(23,'tom5',11),(24,'tom5',11),(25,'tom5',11),(26,'tom5',11),(27,'tom5',11);
40  /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` ENABLE KEYS */;
41  UNLOCK TABLES;
42  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
43  /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
44  /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
45  /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
46  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
47  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
48  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
49  /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
50  -- Dump completed on 2018-12-12  1:02:27
```

the hold space is:

```
 1  
 2  
 3  
 4  
 5  
 6  
 7  
 8  
 9  
10  
11  -- Dump completed on 2018-12-12  1:02:27
```

After '/CREATE TABLE suck_t/!d' is executed, all the lines in the pattern space except line containing CREATE TABLE suck_t is deleted. So the output is:

```
27  CREATE TABLE `suck_t` (
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't get this output when I use the command with your input file. Most linebreaks are missing.

Comment: Read a sed manual to see what those commands do.

Comment: "What does this code do?" questions are generally considered too broad to be permissible here, without narrowing down to be extremely specific (and, ideally, removing everything *unrelated* to that narrow, specific point of contention); showing that you consulted a manual and explaining exactly what aspect is still unclear after reading that documentation helps. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the sed command does:

```
# If a line is non-empty
/./ {
    # Append line to hold space
    H
    # For every line but the last of the file, delete pattern space (print
    # nothing) and start next cycle
    $! d
}

# If we are here, the line was either empty or is the last line

# Swap pattern space and hold space
x

# If the pattern space does not match "CREATE TABLE `suck_t`, delete it and
# start new cycle
/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/! d

# If we are here, the pattern space matches the "CREATE TABLE" pattern from
# above

# Print current line and quit
q
```

In other words: it prints every blank-line-separated paragraph that contains `` CREATE TABLE `suck_t` ``. Since the input file contains only a single paragraph containing that string, the *actual* output is just this:

```
LOCK TABLES `suck_t` WRITE; /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` DISABLE KEYS
*/; INSERT INTO `suck_t` VALUES (1,'tom1',11),(2,'tom2',11),(3,'tom3',11),(4,'tom4',11),(5,'tom5',11),(6,'tom5',11),(7,'tom5',11),(8,'tom5',11),(9,'tom5',11),(10,'tom5',11),(11,'tom5',11),(12,'tom5',11),(13,'tom5',11),(14,'tom5',11),(15,'tom5',11),(16,'tom5',11),(17,'tom5',11),(18,'tom5',11),(19,'tom5',11),(20,'tom5',11),(21,'tom5',11),(22,'tom5',11),(23,'tom5',11),(24,'tom5',11),(25,'tom5',11),(26,'tom5',11),(27,'tom5',11); /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suck_t` ENABLE KEYS */; UNLOCK TABLES; /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

A blank line (`H` inserts one) and the two lines of the third paragraph from the bottom.

Your output contains linebreaks which are neither present in the input nor introduced by the sed script.

---

As for your question about braces: they group commands. If I say

```
/./H;$!d
```

this means "for every line matching `.`, do `H`; then, for every line, delete it unless it is the last line".

On the other hand,

```
/./{H;$!d}
```

means "for every line matching `.`, do `H` and delete it unless it is the last line".

The first command would delete an empty line because `$!d` is run for every line; the second command would skip empty lines entirely.

Comment: My understanding is, after  '/./{H;$!d;}'  is executed, the pattern space includes a bunch of empty lines and the last line, the hold space includes all the non-empty lines.

Comment: My understanding is, after  '/./{H;$!d;}'  is executed, the pattern space includes a bunch of empty lines and the last line, the hold space includes all the non-empty lines.  After 'x' is executed, hold space and pattern space is switched, so the pattern space includes all the non-empty lines and the hold space includes  a bunch of empty lines and the last line. After  '/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/!d' is executed, all the lines except line containing CREATE TABLE `suck_t` is deleted. So the output is CREATE TABLE `suck_t`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @GaryAllen I'm not sure I follow - where in my explanation is your interpretation differing from what I wrote? If you *really* want a deep dive into what's going in, I recommend the [sedsed](https://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/) debugger ([GitHub](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed)): it shows for each command what exactly is in the pattern and hold space.

Comment: Thank you so much, after some debug, I finally understand how it works. sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/!d;q' bak.sql.  1. when lines are not empty, it executes {H;$!d;} until it meets an empty line. 2. when it meets an empty line, {H;$!d;} is skipped, and then 'x;/CREATE TABLE `suck_t`/!d;q' is executed. The logic is, the file content is split by an empty line into many sectors. Sectors not  containing CREATE TABLE suck_t are deleted. The trick is, '/CREATE TABLE suck_t/!d' treats a sector as a single line. This confuses me.

Comment: @GaryAllen Yes, you got it! I think sed is a wonderful little tool that gets you to think in new ways, but it's not always practical to use, and very difficult to retrace when written by somebody else.